# Measure input capacitance of I/O pin

Tags: measurement, capacitance, input

I'm looking for a simple laboratory procedure (and required equipment) to measure the input capacitance of each IC I/O pin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What capacitance range do you expect to see?

Comment: In the range of 2pF to 10pF.

Comment: Does the datasheet not say anything about this?

Comment: Why would you be concerned about output pin capacitance?

Comment: Actually, I'm designing my own chip. The output capacitance is critical for ADC pins due settling time, among other examples.

Comment: Re your last comment, how did you draw that conclusion?

Comment: When you have a analog voltage source with non-zero series impedance, it will create a RC series circuit in relation with the ADC analog input.

Comment: ASIC != cheap labratory equipment

Comment: Changed cheap to simple to be more general.

Comment: Measuring the I/O capacitance is not something as static as a capacitor. If you don’t know the I/O internals you might be reading something absolutely different from the real value